# strange messages in the systemd journal

Tags: linux, systemd, journalctl

I'm running `systemd` version:

```
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

on `5.8.0-54-lowlatency #61~20.04.3`

For some reason my services started spamming the system log with these messages:

```
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: /
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: -1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: /
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: [
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: 1633203968
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: .
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: 541764999
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: ]
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: ERROR
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  ModuleID=7
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  Errcode=1009
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  X=0
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  E=1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  T=1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: /
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: -1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: /
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: [
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: 1633203968
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: .
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: 551844999
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: ]
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: ERROR
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  ModuleID=8
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  Errcode=8
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  X=0
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  E=1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]:  T=1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: /
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: -1
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: /
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: <not found>
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: [
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: 1633203968
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: .
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: 551904999
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: ]
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: ERROR
Oct 02 19:46:08 avionics-fchil2-sim.int.archer.com pitch_bridge[34682]: :
```

It doesn't look like the messages that my application would write. It seem more system related.
Any ideas would be helpful. There is plenty of disk space, so far.

Comment: Looks like some log records formatted like `dmesg`, split by the word bounds. Large numbers are timestamps, etc. Assembled message seems to be like `[1633203968.551844999] ERROR: ModuleID=8 Errcode=8 X=0 E=1 T=1 <not found>/<not found>:-1/<not found>:`. Are you sure your application couldn't output this?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - I'm fairly certain that it isn't my application. But it could the libraries I link with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. One the [libraries](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-micro/2.4.1/doc/html/group__LoggingModule.html) we are using is sending this message.